# Administer NFS gateway (Hortonworks stack)

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I believe in the latest version of Ambari (2.1.1) you can administer NFS gateways via the front-end. When I navigate to the HDFS service summary I see the NFSGateways hyperlink (NFSGateways 0/0 Started) but when clicking on this link there is no option to start a new NFS3 gateway and I have to resort to the command line (Hadoop nfs3) command to start it up.

I've had a trawl around but can find no documentation on how to start NFS up via Ambari, does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "NFSGateways 0/0 Started" means you have no such components installed.
On hosts page, go to some host page, choose "Add component" and select NFS Gateway. After installing start it. You should be able to use it then

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for!  Thanks for the help!